# Does two variable integrand equivalent to 0, if integral equivalent to 0?

Tags: calculus, integration

If

$\int_0^x G(x, t) dt \equiv 0$

where $G(x, y)$ is an absolutely continuous function of two variables on triangle $[0, \pi]\times[0,x]$.

Does it follow that $G(x, y) \equiv 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think that $G=0$. For example choose
$$G(x,y)=y-\frac{x}{2}.$$
Then
$$\int_0^x G(x,y)\, dy = \left[\frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{x}{2}y\right]^x_0 = 0.$$